Nextjs: Error: (0 , _TestCartContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useCart) is not a function
He replicado este error en formato testeo para probar cosas en menor formato pero no entiendo por que no deja de saltarme este error aqui y en el proyecto. He revisado varias preguntas y respuestas, vuelto a armarlo todo y al final siempre me salta lo mismo "Error: (0 , TestCartContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.useCart) is not a function". A veces el modulo 1, 4, 9, ..... ¿ Que es lo que falla ?
Documentaciones relacionadas.

React: createContext
React: useContext
React: Escalar con reducer y contexto
React: Extraer lógica de estado en un reducer



page.tsx

/// app/(delete)/test/page.tsx

import { CartProvider, useCart } from './TestCartContext';

// [X] Vamos a crear una página con un producto simple
// [X] Un botón para añadir al carrito
// [-] Y resolver la lógica de añadir al carrito

const productos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'Producto 1',
    precio: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: 'Producto 2',
    precio: 200,
  },
];

export default async function Home() {
  // const addToCart = (id) => useCart().addToCart({ id, name: 'Producto', quantity: 1, price: 100 });
  const { addToCart } = useCart();
  // const addToCart = useCart();

  const manageOnClick = () => {
    return addToCart({
      id: productos[0].id,
      name: productos[0].nombre,
      quantity: 1,
      price: productos[0].precio,
    });
  };

  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {/* Your components that use the cart context */}
      <main role="test">
        <h1>Productos</h1>

        <h2>{productos[0].nombre}</h2>
        <p>{productos[0].precio}€</p>
        <button onClick={() => manageOnClick}>Añadir al carrito</button>

        {/* <ul>
          {productos.map((producto) => (
            <li key={producto.id}>
              <h2>{producto.nombre}</h2>
              <p>{producto.precio}€</p>
              <button onClick={manageOnClick}>Añadir al carrito</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul> */}
      </main>
    </CartProvider>
  );
}


CartContext

/// app/(delete)/test/TestCartContext.tsx

'use client';

import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

interface CartItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
}

interface CartContextType {
  cart: CartItem[];
  addToCart: (item: CartItem) => void;
  removeFromCart: (id: number) => void;
  clearCart: () => void;
}

const CartContext = createContext<CartContextType | null>(null);

export const CartProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<CartItem[]>([]);

  const addToCart = (item: CartItem) => {
    setCart((prevCart) => [...prevCart, item]);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (id: number) => {
    setCart((prevCart) => prevCart.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{ cart, addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCart = () => {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useCart must be used within a CartProvider');
  }
  return context;
};


En la definición de useCart se declara la siguiente validación:

throw new Error('useCart must be used within a CartProvider');

Esto verifica que se este usando el CartContext dentro del CartProvider, observa como no lo estas usando dentro del provider:
export default async function Home() {
  //...codigo
  //el hook useCart esta siendo llamado fuera del provider CartProvider
  const { addToCart } = useCart();
  //...codigo
  
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {/* Your components that use the cart context */}
      {/* ...codigo...*/}
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

Ahora, hay otro error encima:

useCart is not a function

Esto sucede cuando se trata de injectar una dependencia de tipo react custom hook dentro de un server component, si agregas la directiva "use client" hasta arriba del componente Home y lo transformas a un componente cliente, entonces resuelves el primer error, luego vendrá el error useCart must be used within a CartProvider.
Para finalizar, lo correcto dentro de Home es crear un child component, que quede entre CartProvider y que por estar usando un custom hook deberá de ser un componente cliente:
//pseudocidigo server component
      <CartProvider>
           <MiComponenteQueConsumeUnContexto />
        </CartProvider>


"use client"
function MiComponenteQueConsumeUnContexto(){
   const { addToCart } = useCart();
   return null;
}


Tienes razón, en el ejemplo Test que cree no lo estaba usando dentro del Provider, me di cuenta antes, aunque en proyecto real, por defecto, sí.
Voy a revisar lo siguiente .. !

Wow muchas gracias. He creado el componente "AddToCart.tsx" con la directiva de "use client"; arriba y lo he importado a la página del producto, sigo trabajando a partir de ahí. Enhorabuena, ten un excelente día!
